# How to make database connection with oracle in delphi xe2 using TADOConnection?

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to make a database connection with Oracle using the `TADOConnection` component. I added a `ADOConnection1` to the form. Then I set the `Provider` property to "SQLOLEDB". Consider username and password of database is 111 and 222 respectively.

Now on the `OnShow` event of the form I am trying to make the database connection.

I have written a `MakeConnection` function called by the `OnShow` event handler:

```
function Tabc.MakeConnection : boolean;
var 
  ConnString : string;
begin
  result := false;
  try
    ADOConnection1 := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
    ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := ConnString;
    ADOConnection1.LoginPrompt := false;
    ADOConnection1.Open;
    result := true;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

My question is, what should be the format of the `ConnString` variable? Should I use "SQLOLEDB" as provider or anything else?

**Update:**

Earlier I have created a connection to an Microsoft SQL Server whose connection string format is:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Password=222;Persist Security Info=False;User ID= 111;Initial Catalog= abcde;Data Source= datasource\SQLEXPRESS;Initial File Name="";Server SPN=""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***1. Oracle Database provider:***

To connect to the Oracle Database you need at least use a different connection provider in your current situation. Microsoft has its own [`Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it is deprecated and, as it's stated in the reference, you should avoid using it (link to Oracle’s OLE DB provider added by me):

> **Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle**
>
> This feature will be removed in a future version of Windows. Avoid
>   using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify
>   applications that currently use this feature. Instead, use [**Oracle’s
>   OLE DB provider**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/index-089115.html).

The Oracle Provider for OLE DB you can then in your connection string use [`this way`](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#oracle-provider-for-ole-db-oraoledb):

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle
```

***2. Oracle Database connection string attributes:***

To your next question about Oracle Database specific connection string attributes, the best you can do is to follow [`the reference`](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featConnecting.htm#i1006259).